# Create logins for all active directories groups named ("Domain Users"), related to current Windows Authenticated user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, windows, windows-server, active-directory

I need to get all active directories locations, related to current machine, by SQL script to create logins for them. Is there a way to perform that? For now I wrote such procedure:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [**Location**\Domain Users] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
```

Is there a way to get all locations using SQL query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "*location*"?...an Active Directory Domain?

Comment: @J.D. Yes. The main idea here is to get all that domains and create logins for their groups with a specific naming.

Comment: Sounds a bit weird: how many AD domains do you have? There is normally only one or a handful, so you should just be able to copy/paste out of the "Active Directory Users and Computers" pane. Or Powershell `Get-ADTrust -Filter *` will get you all domains you trust other than your own.